# passing parameters through yield to section laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm having a problem with the blade views. I'm creating a variable, and there is a @yield where i set its content in another page.

layout.blade.php:

```
@php $x = 5 @endphp
@yield('content')
```

I want to pass this variable through the yield so it could be accessed in the other page.

content.blade.php:

```
@extends('layout')
   @section('content')
      {{$x}}
   @endsection
```

the content section is in a loop and the value for x is changing so it couldn't be passed from the controller.
so is there a way to pass data from @yield to @section?

Comment: Read about [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers), with these callbacks you can pass any params in a view.

Comment: @smokehill view composer passes the data to the layout and it is extended to the views but my case is the value for that variable is changing in the layout page and for every time it is changed the yield is called with the new value

Comment: we can use the controller, but consider the methods to update and other controllers using the layout. wishing for @yield('content', ['x' => $x])

Answer (score 0):

You should Have a structure of Html in layout.blade.php to see it in content.blade.php

for example if you want to see it in title :

```
    @php $x = '5'; @endphp

    <html>
      <head>    
        <title>@yield('content', $x)</title>
      </head>

    <body></body>
    </html>
```

In content.blade.php:

```
@extends('layout')
```

Comment: I have multiple views that can extend that layout so include will work for only one of them not the rest

Comment: using
     @yield('content', $x)

gives me Undefined variable: x in the content.blade.php

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: I find the solution please check the edited code and say result

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work also, from the search I found that the child renders before parent so the content.blade file renders before layout so the variable named x is not yet created or assigned a value so it's undefined in the child view.
there is no way to pass data through yield but it is possible through include but I had to do some work around to make it work with the multiple views that i have.
thanks for your effort you are the man.

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable in your `app.layout` file

```
@php $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') @endphp
```

then use it in the `blade` file within curly brackets like in `nav.blade.php`

```
Date: {{$date}}
```